# html frames problem

Tags: html

I have used html frames to create a page. It has 3 frames linked with 3 different pages. Now in one frame there is a logout option. When i press that button it only changes in that frame. I want that when i logout, all the other frames must be removed and just a single page. Please tell me if there is a way..

Comment: Sounds like you would need JS to remove the frames. Can you paste your code thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the logout success page, put this javascript in the head tags:

```
   if (top.location!= self.location) {

   top.location = self.location.href

        }
```

Comment: This is fine, but works only with JavaScript enabled, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the logout link `target="_top"`:

```
<a href="logout.html" target="_top">
```

that will destroy the frameset, and redirect the user to the logout page in the full window.

Answer (score 0):

set the target of your logout-form (or link, depending on what you're using) to `_top`. for more information, take a look at [this](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_TARGET.html).